# Singapore entry visa application after blacklisting

Tags: visas, singapore

How do I apply for a visa after the Singapore immigration blacklist period expires? My offense was carrying too many cigarettes and I was imprisoned for 3 months.

Answer (score 18):

No one can say if Singapore will re-admit you; the only way to know is to apply.

Remember that the Singapore authorities will know about your offense and the blacklist; if asked on the visa application about prior criminal acts or blacklisting, you should answer truthfully. Remember that the imprisonment and blacklist appy to you as a person, and not to your passport; getting another passport won't help you. Because Singapore knows that you violated the law once before, your application task will be to convince the Singapore visa examiner that this time you'll obey the law.

They may be convinced, or they may not. I would guess that your chances of success are low.

Comment: Very good answer. I'd like to add that Singapore's ICA is quite opaque in its handling of Immigration, from tourists to PR, and rarely if ever publishes any definite rules.